# How to clean a line read from a txt file to match literal string

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, drive

If I read a line from a txt file with one single line, I can't seem to be able to make that line match a string that litterally is exactly the same

this is my code:

I've uploaded a text file to myfolder in google drive called 'code.txt' that has one single line that reads 'Code123' (with no quotes), but although i can open an read that line, no matter what I do I can´t seem to be able to clean it so it can match a string that reads also Code123

```
folder_files = glob.glob('drive/MyDrive/myfolder/*')
codefile_path = ''
for file_path in folder_files:
  if 'code.txt' in file_path:
      codefile_path = file_path
codefile = open(codefile_path, "r")
lines = codefile.readlines()
codefile.close()
code2 = 'Code123'
code = lines[0].strip()
print(code2) #this prints Code123
print(code) #this also prints Code123
print(code == code2) #yet this line always prints False
```

What am I missing?

I've tried creating and reading the txt file with encoding = utf-8
I've tried cleaning the line by replacing \n for '', also cleaning it up with lstrip, rstrip.. both together, but nothing changes.
one thig i noticed is that if I do print(code2 in code) it does give True, which leads me to believe that there is some characters or caracter that is not space or a carriage return that is still in the string read from the file line.
I've been at this for hours now... thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

strip(), does take take care of any \n or spaces but doing a len() would confirm that both lines were in fact of different lengths which clearly shows both variables were holding different values.

what helped was taking care of any non-alpha numerical values with the help of re.sub() and a regex expression taken from [this post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-string)

```
import re
code = lines[0].strip()
code = re.sub(r'[\W_]', '', code)
```